# PHP: Get value of id from a table

Tags: php

I have a table which I load with values from the database. The table has an update button which I want to pull specific data values from the database based on the id.

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $result['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowcount ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['Level Date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['Recieve Date'];?></td>
    <td><button type="button" name ="updateid" id="updateid" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previous-detail-modal"> Update</button></td>
```

Can you advice on how I can get the value of $result['id'] of that particular row so I can use it in a function. Currently it keeps taking the last row count value

I tried many solutions reading the posts from others but I am not able to get the value. Would appreciate some help on this

Comment: you can use javascript for that

Comment: What does this button do, exactly?  Do you need the ID client-side or server-side?  Currently you just have a button outside of any form, clicking it does nothing.

Comment: @David, thank you. The button currently opens a modal dialog, I need the id on the client side to go in to a function that that populates the  modal fields based on the id.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR, I tried Javascript $('#updateid').click(function(){ ('#modal-id').val(value of updateid)}). but it loads after the button is clicked and modal loads up

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I need the id on the client side

You can emit the ID from your PHP code onto the button itself as a data attribute, the same way you emit it anywhere else:

```
<button type="button" name="updateid" id="updateid" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="<?php echo $result['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previous-detail-modal">Update</button>
```

Then in your client-side code, wherever you're handling the button click or otherwise identifying the button, you can pull the data attribute from that button.  For example, if you have a reference to the element in a variable called `myButton`:

```
let id = myButton.dataset.id;
```

*Edit:* In a comment on the question you show the use of jQuery.  In that case you might pull the data value with that:

```
let id = $('#updateid').data('id');
```

Comment: Hi David, can you give me more information on referencing the element in a variable. I updated my button with data-id, and now I want to access it in my modal. How do I retrieve it? I tried buttonname.dataset.id, but it gives me a warning.